# Redirect URL format

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to redirect URLS matching one format to another? For example:
www.domain.name/files/user/{something}/docs
to
sub.domain.name/{something}
And if so, how?

Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.name$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^files/user/.*/docs$ sub.domain.name/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

- NC - No Case - case insensitive.
- L - Last - don't try other rules.
- QSA -
  Query String Append - attaching all
  the ?blah=blue&query=something.

You may put some `RewriteCond`s; they'll apply on the near-by `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to understand it.

Comment: You may ask for clearify. And you should accept this answer ("V") :) .